# Php htaccess 404 Not Found Page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a website and its link structure is like this:

```
site.com/asdsadsad.html -> page.php
site.com/blog/ -> blog homepage
site.com/blog/aksmdlksamdlms.html -> post page
```

And `index`, `contact page` and so on.

All I want to do is to create a htaccess file and check all pages that doesn't exit.

But I don't know how to check pages if they exist or not.

For example, `site.com/blog/simple-post.html` -> this page exists, I can check it, but I can not check the page like `site.com/blog/opepo/klamnsdksa`.

Comment: What you want to do when page is not found?

Answer (score 0):

```
order allow,deny
deny from 255.0.0.0
deny from 123.45.6.
allow from all
```

The above lines tell the Apache Web Server to block visitors from the IP address '255.0.0.0' and '123.45.6.', note the second IP address is missing the fourth set of digits, this means any IP address which matches the firth three set of digits will be blocked, e.g. '123.45.6.10' and '123.45.6.255' would be blocked.

To set-up blocking of all visitors except yourself, create a .htaccess file following the main instructions and guidance which includes the following text:

```
order allow,deny
allow from 255.0.0.0
deny from all
```

Comment: What has this got to do with the question?

Comment: I don't want to block users, I am just trying to determine pages that doesn't exist and redirect the pages to 404.html. Actually it's all about php coding. But I don't know how to determine not existing pages with php.